# Can not get element from layout

Tags: android, layout, android-layout, android-intent

I have 2 activities. The 2nd .xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/TrainsListView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Part of manifest:

```
<activity android:name="TrainsActivity">

</activity>
```

And I'm trying to get TrainsListView:

```
mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.TrainsListView);
```

But after this mlistView is null. Why?

Comment: I want to know have you extended ListActivity or Activity in Your Activity Class.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm guessing this is happening in your Activity's `onCreate()` method because you are calling `findViewById()` before you have called `setContentView()`.  If that's not the case then please show more of your code.

Answer (score 6):

If `findViewById()` is failing to find your target id, here are some reasons this may happen:

[[ In your case, I suspect #1 or #2.]

1. `SetContentView()` (or `inflate`) hasn't been called yet to associate a layout to search yet.
2. `SetContentView()` (or `inflate`) was called with a layout that does not contain the target id, e.g. you specified the wrong layout.
3. There's a typo in the `id` in the layout or in the code.
4. You've imported the wrong `R` file (like a library component's `R` file) and coincidentally the same id was also used in the other `R` file).
5. You're searching the wrong view, e.g. you inflated a menu layout and did not attach it to the root layout and then you attempted to search for an id in the root layout (`findBiewById(..)`) when you meant to search the inflated menu layout (`menu.findBiewById(..)`).